# How to set PHPSESSID in cookie guard

Tags: php, cookies

I am using cookie guard from http://cookieguard.eu/Default.aspx and need to configure PHPSESSID to authenticate different users of the site. What is happening is that it seems to be setting a cookie for the whole site rather than users. How can I amend this or trouble shoot the error. Is 'PHPSESSID' correct in the code or do I manually have to set up the id's in there.

I am not very experienced with cookies so any help would be invaluable. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $.cookieguard();
    $.cookieguard.cookies.add('PHP Session', 'PHPSESSID', 'This cookie is used to track important logical information for the smooth operation of the site', true);
    $.cookieguard.run();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Session cookies are per session, which means it ties the browser's session to the user for that site. You can't (easily) have multiple users signed in on the same browser with a separate session cookie, because the cookie name (PHPSESSID) is going to be the same, so starting a session for UserB will kick out UserA's session cookie.  You would need to have the server name the session cookie something more unique to get around this, but it sounds like you are trying to hack from the client side, so probably can't control that.

Comment: @Anthony so I am clear on this. If a site has multiple users, they all have the same PHPSESSID? Thanks

Comment: No. If a site has multiple users each session gets a different session id and a user uses the same one until the cookie expires or is revoked or whatever. But the cookie name is always PHPSESSID. and you can't have multiple cookies with the same name even if the values are different.

Comment: I have checked and each user seems to be getting the same SESSION value. How do I check if sessions are behaving ok. Thanks